# Spring Cloud Gateway Custom Filter : WebClient.create().post() causes hanging when testing

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

So I've created a custom filter that, when accessed, will create a webflux client and post to a predetermined url. This seems to work fine when running, but when testing this code the test is hanging (until I cancel the test). So I feel there is a possible memory leak on top of not being able to complete the test to make sure this route is working properly. If I switch the `WebClient` method to `get()` then a resulting test of the filter works fine. Something with a `post()` I am not sure what is missing.

```
@Component
class ProxyGatewayFilterFactory: AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<ProxyGatewayFilterFactory.Params>(Params::class.java) {
    override fun apply(params: Params): GatewayFilter {
        return OrderedGatewayFilter(
                GatewayFilter { exchange, chain ->
                    exchange.request.mutate().header("test","test1").build()
                    WebClient.create().post()
                            .uri(params.proxyBasePath)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(exchange.request.body))
                            .headers { it.addAll(exchange.request.headers) }
                            .exchange()
                            .flatMap {
                                println("the POST statusCode is "+it.statusCode())
                                Mono.just(it.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful)
                            }
                            .map {
                                exchange.request.mutate().header("test", "test2").build()
                                println("exchange request uri is " + exchange.request.uri)
                                println("exchange response statusCode is "+ exchange.response.statusCode)
                                exchange
                            }
                            .flatMap(chain::filter)
                }, params.order)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the documentation, if using `exchange` you have an obligation to consume the body.

> Unlike retrieve(), when using exchange(), it is the responsibility of the application to consume any response content regardless of the scenario (success, error, unexpected data, etc). Not doing so can cause a memory leak. The Javadoc for ClientResponse lists all the available options for consuming the body. Generally prefer using retrieve() unless you have a good reason for using exchange() which does allow to check the response status and headers before deciding how to or if to consume the response.

[Spring framework 5.2.9 Webclient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-exchange)

This api has been changed in the latest version of the spring framework 5.3.0 now spring will force you to consume the body, because developers didn't actually read the docs.

Comment: how would I do that within the filter?

Comment: there are several examples in the link how you consume the body. for instance `.exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Void.class));` Here i use void because we dont care about the body.

Comment: I'm so new to this reactive stuff... I actually used it.releaseBody() this seems to work also. The body itself still get's passed on through the filter though? I'm not losing it if i don't return it or if I release it?

Comment: i dont really understand what it is you want to achieve with all your mutating and why you are changing the headers and etc. You asked if you had a memory leak and i told you yes, and how to fix it. What your business requirements are i have no idea. I suggest if you are new, is to read the `reactor documentation` and then after that the `webflux documentation` Reactive programming is very different from ordinary programming and not something you can pick up by just googling a little bit.

Comment: if you need the body that you get from the webclient call, at a later time, you need to extract it in the `flatMap` so that webflux can close the underlying tcp-connection. And then pass the body to wherever it needs to be used.